# Возможно ли создать базу данных с текущей датой в названии

Tags: mysql

Используя MySql query возможно ли создать базу данных с датой в названии?

То есть например я хочу назвать базу данных `user(24-11-16)` Что то напримере такого.

То есть query будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
CREATE DATABASE 'users(CURDATE())'
```

Comment: А для чего это нужно? На самом деле дата в названии таблицы это антипаттерн.

Comment: Не увидел что речь про имя БД, в таком варианте это ещё хуже.

Comment: @fens ищу способ копировать мою текущую базу данных добавив дату

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно создать таким образом, идея взята [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15249929/5707560):

```
-- нужно заменить все тире из даты, так как
-- они запрещены в названии базы данных
SET @db_create_query = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE', ' ', 'user_', REPLACE(CURDATE(), '-', '_'));

PREPARE stmt_create FROM @db_create_query;
EXECUTE stmt_create;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_create;
```